# push notification to apple using jdsoftnotification in c# not working from last 2 days

Tags: push-notification

private NotificationService ConfigureNotificationService(bool sandbox, string p12File, string p12FilePassword)
        {
            //Actual Code starts below:
            //--------------------------------

```
        string p12Filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, p12File);

        NotificationService service = new NotificationService(sandbox, p12Filename, p12FilePassword, 1);

        service.SendRetries = 5; //5 retries before generating notificationfailed event
        service.ReconnectDelay = 60000; //5 seconds

        service.Error += new NotificationService.OnError(service_Error);
        service.NotificationTooLong += new NotificationService.OnNotificationTooLong(service_NotificationTooLong);

        service.BadDeviceToken += new NotificationService.OnBadDeviceToken(service_BadDeviceToken);
        service.NotificationFailed += new NotificationService.OnNotificationFailed(service_NotificationFailed);
        service.NotificationSuccess += new NotificationService.OnNotificationSuccess(service_NotificationSuccess);
        service.Connecting += new NotificationService.OnConnecting(service_Connecting);
        service.Connected += new NotificationService.OnConnected(service_Connected);
        service.Disconnected += new NotificationService.OnDisconnected(service_Disconnected);
        return service;
    }
```

alertNotification.Payload.Alert.Body = string.Format("{0} {1} sent you a friend request", "testing", "TESTING");
                                    //  alertNotification.Payload.Badge = totalCount;
                                    alertNotification.Payload.AddCustom("SourceType", "FriendRequest$" + obj.ContentId);

service.QueueNotification(alertNotification);

above is bits of my code which worked fine till last week, now when i tried this is not sending notification to device.. at the end it hits service_Error method the error it is returning is 
"Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.".
tried with 2 to 3 sandbox cerificates but it gives same error
Please help.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Push works with the production certificate, but have the same exception with the developer one. It started some 6 days ago, before it was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

My problem is solved by changing OpenSslStream:

apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);

TO

apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);

Comment: When you should change it? I don't see 'apnsStream' in my code

Comment: The above code is for APNS-Sharp 1.0.4.4 version. If you are using PushSharp newer version, you can find `stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);` in **ApplePushChannel.cs**